# View Shapefile attributes in Autocad?

Tags: shapefile, autocad

I converted my shapefile to autocad.
How can I see my fields in autocad.

[image]

Comment: have you import the attribute data of shapefile as object data?

Comment: I opened it directly from autocad  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fu2yj2ot3oigh2l/4.png?dl=0)

Comment: I'm not very good at aoutocad, but there aint no attribute table as it is in ArcMap. The best I've come up with (as I said, I don't do this a lot) is to write one attribute as annotation that is visible in the dwg. But I did that in FME, I'm guessing you used the Export to CAD function in ArcMap?

Comment: Now what, you want to label your features in AutoCAD?

Comment: I want to see all fields of the shapefile that I converted to Autocad.

Comment: This is likely a question better asked on an AutoCad forum. You can also bring shapefiles directly into AutoCad as an ESRI shapefile (which will retain any fields but formatted in a different manner.

Comment: @ Kazablanka. As far as I know it is not possible to open/import a shapefile in pure AutoCAD. (It is possible to open/import a shapefile in AutoCAD Map 3D and AutoCAD Civil 3D). I can not read your link to dropbox. May you tell me how you have opened/imported the shapefile in AutoCAD?

Answer (score 10):

AutoCAD is a vector drafting software so it doesn't have attributes in the traditional GIS sense like ArcGIS or other GIS's do. Its attributes are meant for the vector (line) parameters such as colour, line thickness, etc. You can add CAD fields to your shapefile and populate those fields with attributes prior to exporting to CAD which will control the visual attributes of those vectors.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with plain AutoCAD without additional coding, since AutoCAD does not provide GIS tools out of the box. I suggest you try [AutoCAD Map 3D](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad-map-3d/overview) or [AutoCAD Civil 3D](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad-civil-3d/overview) applications which do provide rich set if GIS tools to create, edit and view SHP files and related fields (including other GIS-like data sources such as MySQL, SQL Server Spatial, PostGIS, Oracle Spatial, etc.).